# How do you get diffs of all changes associated with a work item?

Tags: tfs, diff

TFS has the ability to display all of the code modified in a folder. In the Source Code explorer, one can click on each code module in the list to get the diff for that module.

(Right-click on a folder in Source Code explorer, Select history in History Select 2 changesets and select Compare)

my workaround: The best I can do so far is to look at the changesets listed in a work item and go plug those numbers in the "compare" query in the source code explorer.

You can't do that in the "links" section of a work item because it is not set up the same way as the source code explorer.

and the query tool in source code explorer won't let you query all changes associated with a single work item.

I'm trying to find a way where I can do this from a single place, so as to be able to review all code as a unified diff (associated with a single work item).

So is my workaround the only real way of doing this?

Starting a bounty.  Is there a Query that can be created?

Answer (score 6):

I needed the same thing but couldn't find a way to do it so I wrote myself a little tool to do that. If a file is edited many times for a work item, the tool lets you see all the files the work item's associated changesets have touched and reach the latest and earliest versions of those files so you can compare.

You can the source code [here](http://etoptanci.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/seeing-all-code-changes-for-a-work-item/) if you like. It is not complete yet but does the trick.

Comment: I've turned it into a modular stand alone tool and put it on codeplex with the name TFS Helper. The module mentioned above is "Work Item File History". You can reach the source code at tfshelper.codeplex.com

Comment: Seems cool.  Any interest to update this for TFS 2015?  Or do you know that the functionality is built-in to the later versions?  Migrate to github?

Answer (score 0):

The [annotate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx) function might help, but you'll have to do it per file, not per folder.

Comment: you could then do a for loop over each file